# Can I hide a .NET in-memory variable from Administrative user with physical access?

Tags: c#, .net, security, memory

Let's say that there's a piece of sensitive information that's stored in memory and it's defined as follows:

```
private readonly String Key;
```

The `Key` variable is assigned a value using an argument passed to the constructor of the owning class. That value is obtained via a `Console.ReadLine()` call that takes place via a helper app. That console app is then closed after the value is propagated where it's supposed to go. The value is never written or read to a file or the registry. It's purely an in-memory kind of deal.

It's really important that this key not be made known to anyone, including the various consultants who may have Administrator access on the domain, not to mention physical access to the computer.

I've been trying to come up with some bullet-proof way to protect this `Key` value but I can't really come up with anything. Am I correct in assuming that anyone with Administrative access could simply launch Visual Studio, attach to the process, and then track down the value of `Key`?

Again, just to be clear. We can tolerate the destruction of the physical machine or the theft of any data residing on that machine. The only thing we can't tolerate is the loss or theft of in the in-memory `Key` while the app is running.

(This app is running on .NET 4.5, Windows 2008 Server)

Any ideas?

Comment: Using the Data Protection API via the `ProtectedData` class to encrypt in-memory data using the user's logon credentials would probably be a good start.

Comment: @mikez: Admin process can just debug the app and call CryptUnprotectMemory on it. DPAPI is used to ensure secrets aren't leaked into crash dumps and other diagnostic information, not to prevent attacks where an attacker can read anything from your process.

Comment: @mikez: Also keep in mind that in the case of the CLR specifically if you've ever put the data in the unencrypted form onto the GC heap you have no way of destroying it because the GC will not deterministically reclaim it.

Comment: @BillyONeal Can you call CryptUnprotectMemory on another user's data? The API seems designed at least to prevent other users from getting at the unencrypted data. Of course you are correct about unencrypted data on the CLR heap. Best bet would be to put the sensitive data on a machine that the untrusted users do have access to (physical or otherwise).

Comment: @mikez: Yes, you can. In this scenario the attacker is a debugger. Even if `CryptUnprotectMemory` will not work unless the decryption happens in the same process (it can be configured to do so), a debugger can inject a DLL / thread into that process to call `CryptUnprotectMemory` on its behalf.

Comment: @BillyONeal Ahh yes, I hadn't considered that. Even without a debuger you could easily inject a dll to get at the data then.

Comment: What a relief that you've disabled virtual memory! Hate to have that data paged or swapped out to something more persistent.

Comment: @HABO: Reading the paging file requires administrative access, so that's not actually a vulnerability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent someone with physical access from reading memory; they'd always be able to probe the physical memory bus. And in user mode, you can't even prevent other administrative programs from reading memory; as you said they can just attach as a debugger.

There are systems designed to make it difficult to get to keys stored on physical devices (e.g. the Trusted Platform Module, smart cards, modern video game consoles, Blu-ray players, etc.) but these things make it difficult, not impossible, and aren't available to Joe .NET App.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the X Y problem; however in this case X is most likely along the same lines of "How do I protect some Z from other Administrators." The answer boils down to "You don't." You minimize Administrator access to the machine running the critical component. If it's this critical, you don't even think about shared hosting either. You either host it yourself or go cage hosting. Yes, it's expensive, but it's the only reasonable way.

I've got a few good tricks, but all of them depend on native code and none of them would withstand a sustained attack.